# How to run tests in rider / visual studio in docker container

Tags: c#, docker, integration-testing

My integration tests have dependency on redis. They have dockerfile included, so everything works in CI. However when running locally from test explorer I have to manually start redis container.

Is there possibility for IDE to automatically run/debug tests in docker containers, so when attemptying to run/debug test in IDE (or maybe even using dotnet test) everything runs in docker?

Please note, that **I want to run/debug tests in docker, not docker in tests**.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like there is no solution to do so right now.

Here is ticket for rider:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-38942
and for visual studio: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-running-unit-tests-in-docker/554907

There are some hacks, which you can do to attach debugger to test project, but all of them require some manual interaction and experience is not as seamless as running/debugging the application.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to do this using the [remote testing feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022) introduced in Visual Studio 17.5.

For example, let's say my solution looks like this, and I want to run `MyLogic.Tests` in a Linux environment via Docker Desktop.

```
MyLogic.sln
   QuantLib
      NQuantLib.dll
      NQuantLib.so.0
      NQuantLibc.so
   testenvironments.json
   MyLogic
      MyLogic.csproj
   MyLogic.Tests
      MyLogic.Tests.csproj
      Dockerfile
```

testenvironments.json:

```
{
  "version": "1", // value must be 1
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "Linux x64",
      "type": "docker",
      "dockerFile": "MyLogic.Tests\\Dockerfile"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note if your environment is uncomplicated, you can just reference the docker image directly instead of a `dockerFile`, such as:

`"dockerImage": "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0"`

In my case, I have an extra dependancy to put into the image, so my `Dockerfile` looks like so:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS base
COPY ["QuantLib/", "/usr/lib/"]
RUN ldconfig
```

You should see in Test explorer that your remote environment is now available for selection:

[image: Visual Studio Remote Environment Selection]

If all is well, Test Explorer should then work pretty much the same as when running directly on the host environment in terms of run and debug.

Answer (score -1):

Why not run the container manually?

1. Install docker to the local machine.
2. Use Docker.DotNet nuget in your test project to work with the docker api.
3. Stop all containers.
4. Start the containers you need from your code manually.
5. Run the tests and clear the state after every one.

Such a way you will get a working environment after the tests (all containers will be running).

Comment: This is not revelant to the question. I want to run tests in docker, not docker in tests

Comment: "stop all containers" - I want to run in docker do decrease impact on my machine, i.e. remove dependency on shared services, not increase it

Comment: And how I'll debug tests running in such way?